# Can NHibernate map an CLR "object" type to a SQL type?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

I'm working on a messaging application that needs to send as part of a message some parameters of C# type "object". My fallback solution is to just serialize the object and store it in the database as a string and deserialize it when necessary.

My question is, what is the general strategy for storing instances of type "object" in SQL using NHibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a [custom IUserType](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/10/15/mapping-different-types-iusertype.aspx) which handles your serialization issues. It can take your Object and persist it in whatever format you like, e.g. `SerializedObjectType nvarchar(max) + SerializedObjectJson nvarchar(max)`.

See [MoneyUserType from NCommon.NHibernate](https://github.com/riteshrao/ncommon/blob/master/NCommon.NHibernate/tests/Domain/MoneyUserType.cs) which persist two columns, Amount and Currency.

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution I went with. I didn't know the if the generic "object" type had an equivalent in SQL.